# Exploiting MD5/Salt Vulnerability in this PHP form?

Tags: php, sql, hash, sql-injection

I've been practicing security-related subjects and this challenge has befuddled me. Note: I can't access any PHP source code, nor can I edit it. I'm only able to view it.

The following is given:

I have two inputs, "user" and "pass"
After 30 times the form is sent, the salt, the hashes and the final solution change. So bruteforce isn't an option (sadly!)
@The bottom of the page (not shown in the code for some reason), it echos that it found 9 users (calling the getnumberofusers() function)
I've managed to extract this:

```
username = root
hashed password = 551e18b35e17017742a8ce4ed27f626e
Token (possibly salt?) = 0St31ez14wOT6jTh
```

What I've attempted thus far with unsuccessful results:

Using SQL injection, select a known MD5 collision as password and send its counterpart as "pass", however the salt is bothering this process. Clearly I couldn't bruteforce this because after 30 attempts the salt would change.
I tried finding the entire list of users but it doesn't print the output anywhere (only errors)
This is the code we receive:

```
<?php
//by Mawekl
//Objective: login as root.
//Objective is NOT:
// - Blind SQLI
// - Bruteforce password/salt/id

#WARNING
#ANTI-BLIND
#for every 30 queries
#all hashes, salt
#and final solution
#will be reset.

function getnumberofusers()
{
    $q = "SELECT 1 FROM `sqlinjection1`";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    return 'Number of users: '  . mysql_num_rows($r);
}

function getinfo($user)
{
    $q = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `sqlinjection1` WHERE `username`='$user'";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(!$r)
        return mysql_error();
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if(!$r)
        return "Username doesn't exists.";
    return $r;
}

function getfullinfo($id)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `sqlinjection1` WHERE `id`=$id";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(!$r)
        return mysql_error();
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if(!$r)
        return "What the hell?!";
    return $r;
}

function confirmpassword($pass, $passcorrect, $salt)
{
    $pass = md5(md5(md5($pass)).$salt);
    return $pass===$passcorrect;
}

function challenge($user, $pass)
{
    $info = getinfo($user);
    if(!is_array($info))
        return $info;
    $confirm = confirmpassword($pass, $info['password'], $_ENV['ST_SALT']);
    if(!$confirm)
        return 'Wrong password!';
    $info = getfullinfo($info['id']);
    if(!is_array($info))
        return $info;
    $returnmessage = "Welcome " . $info['username'] . "!" . PHP_EOL .
    $info['welcomemessage'] . PHP_EOL;
    return $returnmessage;
}

?>
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you have any questions I'd love to clarify my question!

now we can select the welcome message/anything else using sql
$user="1' or exp(~(select * from (select welcomemessage from sqlinjection1 where username='user1')a))  or '1'='1"
but when we found a Secret token (that i wrote up there  ^) hidden in the data base and tried using it this way:

The idea: select the hashed version as `password` using SQL injection so the hashes match.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$salt = "v5IftFb0Tx1Jhp4b";
$hashed = "";
$p = "hello";
$hashed = md5(md5(md5($p)).$salt);

echo "The Query: " . "' AND 1 = 0 UNION SELECT `id`, '$hashed' AS `password` FROM sqlinjection1 WHERE `username` = 'root';#";
?>
```

It echoes the query which we put in the "username" field. In the "password" field we enter "hello".

However it's not working...

but it did not work, anyone has any idea what else can we do? How can we find out what / modify the  $_ENV["ST_SALT"]? as appearently its not the secret token that we  found

Comment: you sure that the salt is applied only on the last of the 3 md5 calls?

Comment: yes thats how it is on their source that i have and posted